# Why can't a closing </p> be omitted if the parent element is an <a> element?

Tags: html

http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#optional-tags

According to the HTML5 Specification:

> A *p* element's end tag may be omitted if the *p* element is immediately
>   followed by an *address, article, aside, blockquote, dir, div, dl,
>   fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr,
>   menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table*, or *ul*, element, or if there is
>   no more content in the parent element and **the parent element is not an
>   *a* element.**

[emphasis mine]

What is that last bit about the parent element not being an `a` tag? Why is this allowed:

```
<div>
<p>text...
</div>
```

But this not:

```
<a>
<p>text...
</a>
```

According to the spec, a `p` tag is theoretically allowed inside of an `a`, http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element, so why the exception?

Comment: [<div>How do you annoy a web developer?</span>](http://xkcd.com/1144/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that's because the `<a>` element is an inline element.

While all the others in the list ( *address, article, aside, blockquote, dir, div etc.* ) are block levels, so they can close other elements' scope, which is not the case with inline elements.

Since the `<a>` element is the only one you're allowed to put a block level element into ( according to the link you have provided ) - that's why they mention particularly this element in the specs.

Comment: Actually, the `a` element has a [transparent content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#transparent) - whether you *can* place a certain element inside it depends on whether its closest non-transparent ancestor allows such an element inside it, so you may not be able place a certain element in an `a` in *all* cases. In other words, `a` itself places no freedoms or restrictions on what elements you can have inside it.

Comment: Technically, it's because `<a>` is an [active formatting element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#formatting) rather than because it's an inline element. So `<b>` and `<i>` for instance have equivalent parser behaviour to `<a>`, but `<span>` does not. But as you say, of the elements with that parser behaviour, only `<a>` is allowed to contain a `<p>`.

Answer (score 2):

Because it doesn't make sense to ALWAYS end a `<p>` tag when an `<a>` tag ends. In the `<div>`'s case, if you are closing the `<div>` you almost certainly want to close the `<p>` too, but that isn't the same for an `<a>`. That hyperlink could carry on to the next paragraph

Comment: ... scratch that, I'm probably reading this wrong. Some example markup would be helpful.

Comment: @BoltClock A hyperlink will carry on to the next paragraph unless you explicitly close it: http://jsfiddle.net/xvsVY/

Comment: Ah, but the question is asking why a closing `</p>` tag is required when the parent is an `a`, not why a closing `</a>` tag is required when the child is a `p`.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, I think it is to give the user a choice. The user might want to leave the paragraph open. Forcing them to close their `<p>` tag themself gives them that decision, rather than making it for them. TL;DR: Closing an anchor doesn't mean I want my paragraph closed too

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is not allowed because of how w3 defines a paragraph:

When talking about how lists cannot be inside of a paragraph the [spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/grouping-content.html#the-p-element):

> A paragraph, in HTML terms, **is not a logical concept, but a structural
>   one**. In the fantastic example above, there are actually five
>   paragraphs as defined by this speciication: one before the list, one
>   for each bullet, and one after the list.

It seems to me that W3 intended paragraphs to be paragraphs of text, not giant hyper links, and they went to some lengths to ensure that.